# VS code `\` underlining for insufficiently long

Tags: visual-studio-code, theorem-proving, lean

I am using [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io), an open source theorem prover and programming language on VS Code. Lots of commands require `'\'` to write math symbols, in the same way that LaTeX does.

The essential difference between Lean on VS Code and LaTeX is that in order to have the math symbol compile (e.g the difference between getting `\forall` and the maths `'forall'` sign) is that an underline must appear whilst you're typing the characters after the `\` sign.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that this underline

1) Doesn't always appear when I type `\`

2) Disappears way too quickly.

My question is: **Is this a bug, or is there a way to change the settings in VS code such that an underline always appears after the `\`?**

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a custom feature of https://github.com/leanprover/vscode-lean, so you should probably open an issue there.

Comment: @SebastianUllrich thank you, I will do this now.